# column.length throwing error in Jquery while using with IE8.0

Tags: jquery

I am passing a collection of columns in jquery but when i am getting length of the columns this is giving one extra 
My Code is below

```
function manageUsersPage() {
this.data=null;
this.edititem=null;
this.columns = [
    [false, 'User Id', 'UserI`enter code here`d', 'readonly', 20, '', null],
    [true, 'User Name', 'fullname', 'readonly', 20, '', null],
    [true, 'Login Name', 'Login', 'string', 15, 'required', null],
    [false, 'Password', 'Password', 'password', 15, '', null],
    [false, 'Confirm Password', 'Password', 'password', 15, '', null],
    [true, 'User Type', 'UserType', 'select', 0, '', ['Hotel-Admin', 'Chain-Admin', 'User']],
    [false, 'Manage Hotels (If Chain-Admin)', 'hotels', 'multiselect', 40, '', null],
    [true, 'Email Address', 'Email', 'string', 30, 'custom[email]', null],
    [true, 'Reservation Delivery', 'ResvDelivery', 'select', 0, '', ['No Email', 'All', 'Failure', 'Failure, Pending', 'Failure, Validation', 'Failure, Validation, Rejected', 'Failure, Validation,Pnding', 'Validation,Rejected,Failure, Pnding', 'Failure, Validation,Pnding,Success']],
    [true, 'RMS Mail Delivery', 'RmsDelivery', 'select', 0, '', ['On', 'Off']],
    [false, "First Name", "FirstName", 'string', 20, '', null],
    [false, "Middle Name", "MiddleName", 'string', 20, '', null],
    [false, "Last Name", "LastName", 'string', 20, '', null],
    [false, "Address", "Address", 'text', 40, '', null],
    [false, "Comments", "Comments", 'text', 100, '', null],
    //[false, "login Status", "Loginstatus", "test", 20, '', null],
    [false, 'Mail Delivery', 'RmsDelivery', 'select', 0, '', ['No Email', 'All', 'Failure', 'Failure, Pending', 'Failure, Validation', 'Failure, Validation, Rejected', 'Failure, Validation,Pnding', 'Validation,Rejected,Failure, Pnding', 'Failure, Validation,Pnding,Success']],
];
this.edittable=null;
```

}

and when i am trying

```
 var columns = this.columns, data = this.data;
          var html = '<form id=' + this.formid + '>';
          html += '<table id=' + this.tableid + ' width=100% class=tableBox>';
         html += '<thead><tr>';
        for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if (!columns[i][0]) continue;
        html += '<th>' + columns[i][1] + '</th>';
}
```

columns.length goes to 17 while columns are 16

Answer (score 0):

I think you code seems right. ***[See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekBNJ/1/)***.

Change the comment like:

```
/* [false, "login Status", "Loginstatus", "test", 20, '', null], */
```

#### According to comment

I check that and seem working fine.

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ekBNJ/5/)***

### At last I got the Error

Your array `this.columns` has trailing `comma(,)` at last before closing of the array.

***REMOVE THAT LAST COMMA*** and everything is fine.

Comment: I have done this if i take only one column in this.columns that time also gives columns.length=2 with ie wile the same code is working fine with firfox and chrome and also with higher version of ie

Comment: have you check with ie8.0 your code is giving length 2 and in firfox giving 1  on line   alert(columns.length);